# Pandas: how to convert an index of int64 years to datetime

Tags: pandas

I have an int64 index representing year values that I want to treat as a timestamp index:

```
df.index
Int64Index([2001,2002,2003], dtype='int64')
```

How do I convert the index to a datetime timestamp in pandas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y')
```