# Pandas: converting int64 years to datetime dsiplaying only the year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe index that looks like this:

```
df.index
Int64Index([1992, 1993, 1994, 1995], dtype='int64')
```

but would like it converted to datetime whilst only displaying the year thereby preserving the above yearly format.

I have tried:
[Pandas: how to convert an index of int64 years to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117397/pandas-how-to-convert-an-index-of-int64-years-to-datetime)

```
import pandas as pd
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y')
```

but this gives me:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1992-01-01', '1993-01-01', '1994-01-01', '1995-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Instead is there a better way I can get something along the lines of:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1992', '1993', '1994', '1995'], dtype='datetime64)
```

Answer (score 3):

What about [PeriodIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.PeriodIndex.html)?

```
In [131]: i = pd.Int64Index([1992, 1993, 1994, 1995], dtype='int64')

In [132]: pd.PeriodIndex(i, freq='A')
Out[132]: PeriodIndex(['1992', '1993', '1994', '1995'], dtype='period[A-DEC]', freq='A-DEC')
```

Comment: May be I needed much more research ;0

Comment: @Bharath, yeah, it took me a couple of minutes to recall the name of this class :-) Pandas API is so huge...

Comment: But whenever there is an answer from you guys I will  never forget that. It hits so hard how much I dont know : )

Comment: @MaxU, i tried your method but i got a ValueError: Invalid frequency: Y

Comment: @Folarin, try 'A' instead. I tested it against Pandas 0.21.0. Most probably you have an older version

Comment: @MaxU yes i tried 'A' and i got PeriodIndex(['3962', '3963', '3964', '3965'], dtype='period[A-DEC]', freq='A-DEC') which gives year 3962 instead of 1992. Perhaps its my pandas version, i'm using pandas 0.18.1

Comment: @MaxU, yes they are the index in my dataframe, i wish to plot them on a bar chart as the x-axis, so i need just the year. seems like i might have to resort to using the complex matplotlib.dates. i have never gotten a hang of that module

Comment: @Folarin, consider opening a new question about plotting your data. It's always better to specify a small reproducible data set in your question, so people could use such data set for coding...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.PeriodIndex.html), because is not possible create `DatetimeIndex` without `month`s and `day`s:

```
idx = pd.Int64Index([1992, 1993, 1994, 1995])
print (idx)
Int64Index([1992, 1993, 1994, 1995], dtype='int64')

per = pd.PeriodIndex(idx, freq='A')
print (per)
PeriodIndex(['1992', '1993', '1994', '1995'], dtype='period[A-DEC]', freq='A-DEC')
```

Comment: using your method, i got; PeriodIndex(['3962', '3963', '3964', '3965'], dtype='period[A-DEC]', freq='A-DEC') i.e year 3962 to 3965

Comment: But if need Datetimes with only `year`s it not exist in `python`, the closest what you need is `periodindex`. What is reason for datetimes with year only?

Comment: @jezreal, really? thats odd. i was expecting 1992 to 1995 instead. what pandas version are you using?

Comment: oops, you are right, it is wrong output. I use `0.21.0`. But what iis reason for do it? Maybe this is not necessary.

Comment: I think the best is upgrade pandas, maybe bug.

Comment: i plan on plotting the year on a bar chart as the x axis

Comment: If not convert to datetime/period there is some problem with plot?

Comment: @Folarin - What about plot by pandas, matplotlib? `df.plot.bar()`? Or if need specify columns for plot `df[['col1','col2']].plot.bar()` ?

Comment: yes i've already done that, i just have one column with 4 rows corresponding to 1992-1995 year index but i keep getting year 1992.5, 1993.5 and so on in the x axis. i guess i will have to post another question regarding that problem.

Comment: I think here is simpliest solution, only need `df.index = df.index.astype(str)`

Comment: That would have been the best, unfortunately, you cannot have either axis value as a string, your above method will produce a TypeError most likely

Comment: Nope, but plotting df.index as a string will. Conversion to string is not a problem, plotting as a string is

Comment: So if use `df.index = df.index.astype(str)` and then `df.plot.bar()` it is problem?

Comment: yes, you get: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Answer (score -1):

I found this to be useful

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y').year
```

Comment: This does not change the format.